# Is it possible to build planet-sized non-spherical structures?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, material-science, estimation

Beyond certain size and density the celestial objects tend to admit a spherical size.

I wonder if is there a fundamental mass, density or specific strength related number which when surpassed a non-spherical structure inevitably collapse to a spherical mass?

Or put in another way: can an advanced civilization build an enormous starship that's as massive as Earth but have disc or a cylindrical shape?

Comment: Wonder where this idea came from.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is fairly simple, yet complicated. The reason why planets are planet sized objects form a spherical shape is due to the immense force of gravity. Looking at the force of gravity:

$F_g = G{(\rho v)^2 \over r^2}$

As something obtains more mass it generates a stronger gravitational field. If you decide to build a spacecraft as large as a planet, most likely it won't have the same density as a planet does, and therefore wont generate a strong enough gravitational force to 'flatten' all edges to a fairly spherical shape. Large volume, but small overall density. I assume this planet-sized spacecraft will contain empty space as well for people to go about their business.

So to answer your question you most likely would be able to build a planet sized spacecraft without the force of gravity being a big deal. So have at it, and have fun building. Good luck with funding ha.

Answer (score 1):

*By definition,* an object with the mass of a planet will collapse into a sphere. This is primarily due to the IAU definition of 'planet' specifying that a celestial body must be massive enough to pull itself into a sphere by gravity.

Now, if you were asking about volume instead of mass, I could point out that an occupied spaceship would have to be largely filled with light gasses and so could theoretically be the same *size* as a small planet while being a lesser *mass* and thus prevent collapse. There also is a large difference between a large conglomerate object that forms by falling together and a large engineered structure designed to not fall together.

Comment: Good answer. But the IAU definition is based on natural material (rocks, ice); I understood the original question asked if this also applies to artificial material. If you build a high tower on Earth from rocks, at some height it would crumble, but you can get a much taller structure with steel or (in future perhaps) carbon fibres or similar. I guess there must be a limit where even the strongest possible chemical bonds can't support the weight of the structure any more. But I've no idea how to calculate this limit.

Comment: The IAU definition actually doesn't reference material, but that's irrelevant since the things your ship is made of (iron and carbon, for example) are natural materials found in planets anyway. IAU doesn't even specify a *natural* body. The calculations for a steel ship would be the same as the calculations for a rocky planet, substituting the stress properties appropriately: but that calculation is beyond my ken, as well.

Comment: Asher: Yes, sorry I didn't mean the IAU definition specified materials, just that it's meant for planets, whereas the limits for spaceships made of high-tech material might be much larger. I could imagine that a huge spaceship made of carbon nanotube material, for example, could be bigger and heavier than a small planet but not collapse into a sphere, although there will be some limit.

Answer (score 0):

Stars are gaz and plasma, planet can be considered as fluid or deformable material (and have pretty liquid early stage), so spherical shape is natural.

The question is, is it physically possible to have materials that keeps rigid (or could make rigidifying structures) up to these orders of mass. I don't know if the answer can even be known, as I'm not sure we can really predict all the mechanical charasteristics of all mix and arrangements of all possible atoms, including unknown alloys and cristal forms.

Plus, beside passive structure, you could have active structures with the help of magnetic fields, coolers, adaptive motion, or even constant rebuilding (as in living cells).

Anyway, I'm curious: how could this question possibly be homework ? :-)